# Piping multiple commands

Tags: macos, command-line, bash, unix

I would like to run the following command and pipe stout of both to TextEdit:

```
pmset -g; echo; pmset -g assertions | open -f -a TextEdit
```

This doesn't work, it only executes the latter:

How?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Aahhh, `bash` redirection :-

```
( pmset -g && echo && pmset -g assertions ) | open -f -a TextEdit
```

That runs your commands as a single bash command (that's the effect of `&&`) in a sub-shell (which is what wrapping it in the `()` does) and redirects the output of the sub-shell into TextEdit for you. You technically don't have to use `&&` instead of `;` but the effect of changing it is that if any of the commands fail it will stop the entire chain at that point.

Note: In your example all the commands are being run (as you can prove by just running `pmset -g; echo; pmset -g assertions` at the command line), it's just that you are applying the pipe to only the last one. That's why it needs to be run in a subshell.

Note: that you could replace the `|` character with `>` and send the output to a file if you wish.

Comment: This little tip has been incredibly helpful. The ins & outs of built in commands/ special characters are scarcely documented. Thank you again.

Answer (score 4):

()'s combine the commands into a single process, concatenating them to stdout:

```
(pmset -g; echo; pmset -g assertions) | open -f -a TextEdit
```